# Create a div under navbar-inner that seamlessly continues its gradient

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website using bootstrap and my header is a navbar-inner class.

In some pages I need to put another div of a different class right under navbar-inner and I want it to seamlessly continue to use the same gradient so that the user feels like it is a continuation of the header.

Probably I can find a way to calculate the gradient of the navbar-inner and make another one starting with the ending color of that, but this won't look nice since the height both of the navbar and of the other div change dynamically.

Can anyone suggest a good approach for combining the gradient styling across a dynamic number of div elements?

Thank you

Comment: Can you set the gradient on the navbar and also have the div inside the navbar, after navbar-inner? Both the navbar-inner and the div after it would have transparent backgrounds in this case?

Comment: Yeah, that would be possible. Anyway that will make the code really hard to read and to maintain since the content of the second div belongs to the body of the app and I will need to recreate the structure of the body just for this div. Also this is a ruby on rails app and the code is divided in snippets. For ease of maintenance I prefer not to close every div that I open within its own snippet. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would think that it would be _easier_ to close each div in the same place you opened it...

Comment: -1 What is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the same lines as what @Ana suggested, I think the easiest way is to wrap them together in one element. Rather than nest them, I would wrap them both as siblings in a parent div, which would have the desired styling. That way the gradient and height adjusts automatically, whether or not you include the second div on a given page.